# Any experiences in prototyping with justinmind prototyper creating custom html/css components?

Tags: html, prototyping, mockups, mockup-tool, justinmind

Assuming to have a corp.design-styleguide with lots of div-containers and div-widgets in html with images and css-styling and jquery and so on.

Is it possible to define such widgets as HTML-widgets in justinmind prototyper?
how can I underlay specific images and css to such a custom component?
til now, I haven't found a way to do this. is it possible or not?
any desktop prototyping tool known to rock such tasks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "HTML Website" widget to include a folder with the html, the images and all the css files.